# Symfony3 type-ahead / auto complete

Tags: textbox, symfony, type-ahead

I'm looking for an good example for a type-ahead or auto-complete textbox in Symfony3. When entering text in the textbox then a query is executed to search in a database and the results can be selected.

Any suggestion how to implement this in Symfony3? Where to find a good working example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeahead.js as a JQuery include:
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Here is a simple example:
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

It should be easy to do in Symfony regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is more the standard way of doing auto complete, I was wondering if there was a specific Symfony 3 solution/component that I can use. But if that is not available I will go the standard way. Thanks.

Comment: I did also a search and found this one: https://github.com/lifo101/typeahead-bundle  however I think the twitter typeahead.js is a better solution. I think it would be easier to implement, that initially why I recommended that route.

Comment: Mybe This gits: https://gist.github.com/aimeric/f98af4a3f728bea9e3c9a0918d2a7e2b can help anyone

Answer (score 0):

A code from a project I used these days using Jquery, FosJsRouting and [Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead):

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        highlight: true,
        source: function (valor, process) {
            var search = Routing.generate('YOUR_ROUTE_NAME', {value: value});                
                return $.get(search, function (data) {
                    states = [];
                    map = {};
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        map[state.id] = state;
                        states.push(state.id);
                    });
                    return process(states);
                });                
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            //After select use the option you selected
            $(".table tbody").append('<tr><td>map[item].id</td></tr>');

        },
    });
```

I used `id` as the parameter I wanted to choose from Json, but you could choose any parameter.